# The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o image_srv .' returned a non-zero code: 2

Tags: go, docker-compose, build, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker file using docker-compose. Part of the build is related to go language. When I build the code I get the following error. What could be the issue? How do I fix this error ? Could you please advise? I am new to go language

```
 ---> Running in 68f94f330d0b
Removing intermediate container 68f94f330d0b
 ---> 7a9ca17f7bd7
Step 15/16 : RUN go build -o image_srv .
 ---> Running in 38fa96ef75d6
# golang.org/x/sys/unix
/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall.go:83:16: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix.go:118:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/sysvshm_unix.go:33:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o image_srv .' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: If you look at the [docs for `unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice) you can see that it was added in go1.17. Are you using an out of date version of Go?

Comment: I am using ```FROM golang:1.13-alpine``` in my docker file.

Comment: I only see a docker image for go 1.15, I do not see any docker image for go 1.17. I changed it to ```FROM golang:1.15-alpine``` but the issue still exists.

Comment: The only supported versions of Go are the current release go1.19, and the prior release, go1.18. There are numerous docker images available with different base configurations.

Comment: Are they for linux? could you please share the link?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/golang

Answer (score 0):

You can find appropriate 1.17 tags by going to https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/tags?page=1&name=1.17

Probably `golang:1.17.13-alpine` will suite your use case

Take note that you may need to delete any existing docker images so that the image can rebuild

```
# list docker images
$ docker image ls

# delete image foobar
$ docker rmi foobar
```